# What does SlerpUnclamped do?

Tags: unity, vector, lerp

Unity has a [Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) method:

```
public static Vector3 Slerp(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float t);
```

Where it returns an interpolated position between a and b by the percentage of t.  So if t = 0.5, and a = Vector3.zero, and b = Vector3.one, it returns a Vector3 of (0.5, 0.5, 0.5).

But what does [SlerpUnclamped](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.SlerpUnclamped.html) do?

```
public static Vector3 SlerpUnclamped(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float t);
```

t is not clamped between 0 and 1.  So what what is t relative to?  How do you use this method?

Comment: Unclamped would mean that you can get points on the spherical interpolation curve that lie beyond the initial vectors. (After all the SLERP curve is defined by a mathematical function). So a `t` value  > 1 would mean a point on the curve that lies beyond vector `b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unclamped would mean that you can get points on the spherical interpolation curve that lie beyond the initial vectors. (After all the SLERP curve is defined by a mathematical function). So a `t` value  > 1 would mean a point on the curve that lies beyond vector `b`

Thanks @UnholySheep for the answer!